# NativePageTransitions ionic 2

Tags: navigation, ionic2, transition

I'm trying to use the NativePageTransitions plugin from telerik with ionic 2 to use a fade transition but with no luck. The docs are pretty poor on this subject.

What's the proper way to use it with Ionic 2?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is fading your only reason to use this plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
this.navCtrl.push(NewPage, {}, {
        direction: 'back', // default for push is 'forward'
        duration: 2000, // 2 seconds
        easing: 'ease-out' // fade-in, fade-out
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an late answer but however, if you have not solved this problem, try the following:

1. Install the cordova and ionic plugins by running the following commands:

> ionic cordova plugin add com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/native-page-transitions

2. Add this plugin to your app's module. Check the following link to reference:

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module

Then, you can use this plugin in your app. For configuration, please visit the following link under the documentation:

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/

Please take in mind that you should be testing in a device to see the effect of this plugin. Otherwise, you will see nothing in a computer.